# Parallel optimization and "sinking" intermediate output in R

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing

I have a pretty ugly function to minimize over 7 variables.
To speed up things I got (SSH) access to a cluster where I can run it on 24 cores.

The problem is that the process crashes without fail after a few days, I am not sure why that is but my question is on something else:

How do I get DEoptim to print the output of each cycle (I hope it finishes at least one of them before crashing) in a .Rout file that I can look at after the process crashes (or I stop it)?
This should be the same kind of output for each of the 24 cores but I would hope it is possible to get DEoptim to output all of them.

This is what I have tried but without luck (empty file at the end)

```
clusterEvalQ(cl ,library(snow)) # loads lybrary on nodes 
clusterEvalQ(cl ,library(DEoptim))
clusterEvalQ(cl ,library(cubature))

clusterExport(cl,ls())      # Exports all variables to all nodes
                            # puts all the rra values in a matrix (vector) 


zz <- file("all.Rout", open = "wt")
sink(zz)
sink(zz, type = "message")
print(system.time(parOutput<-parLapply(cl,CornerList,ParFunction)))
i<-1
while(i<= 24){
print(parOutput[[i]][[1]][1])
print(parOutput[[i]][[1]][2])
i <- i+1
}
sink(type = "message")
sink()



stopCluster(cl)
```

Taking away the sink type = "message" does not help.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example isn't working because you're executing `sink` on the master which has no effect on the workers.

You could use the makeCluster `outfile=""` option to allow the worker output to go to your terminal, however that doesn't work in all R environments, such as RStudio. The documentation for `makeCluster` says you can specify a file name with `outfile` and all the workers will log to that file, but I've found that a lot of the output is lost, so I don't recommend that.

If you don't mind using one file per worker, you can execute your `sink` commands on each of the workers as follows:

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(4)

clusterApply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i) {
  zz <<- file(sprintf('all-%d.Rout', i), open='wt')
  sink(zz)
  sink(zz, type='message')
})

r <- parLapply(cl, 1:100, function(i) {
  cat(sprintf('executing task %d\n', i))
  sqrt(i)
})

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  sink(type='message')
  sink()
  close(zz)
  rm(zz)
})

stopCluster(cl)
```